# How to get the url of my hyperlink field within a gridview in a javascript function

Tags: javascript

This is my hyperlink code:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="UnlinkedUsers"  clientIDMode="static" runat="server"
 onclick ="GetSecurity();"  
 NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("LinkUsers.aspx?User={0}&Type={1}",
 Eval("Email"), Eval("EntityType")) %>'Text='Link User'>
```

And this is my JavaScript Code:

```
<asp:Content ID="ContentPlaceHolderJS" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderJS" runat="server">
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
```

**JS**

```
function GetSecurity() {
    var linkUrl = $(this).attr("href");

    //alert(linkUrl);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Dashboard.aspx/CheckSecurity",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        //data: '{"UserName":"' + userName + '"}',
        data: '{"objectname":"LinkUsers"}',
        //data: '{"objectname":"' + objectname + '"}',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d == false)
                alert("You do not have rights to this object.");
            else
                window.location.href = linkUrl.toString();
        }
    });
}
```

This is not working. Specifically this line:

```
var linkUrl = $(this).attr("href");
```

On the browser I am getting the error:

> TypeError: a.attributes is undefined
>
> ...e.cssText}f&&a.setAttribute(b,""+d);if(!a.attributes[b]&&a.hasAttribute&&!a.hasA...

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

`this.getAttribute('href')`